A disk read error occurred Press Ctrl + Alt + Del to restart" after power outage
I am getting "A disk read error occurred Press Ctrl + Alt + Del to restart" after power outage during Gparted (resize/move) process of C partition.
I was trying to resize and move my C partition so that I can  clone C partition to smaller hard drive.



Your partition is gone. Time to restore your data from a backup

Does it matter? You've tagged this as a Win7 PC. Time for another OS.

how can i recover my partition, i connect my HDD to another system and went to disk management and found D partition where deleted partition was, as RAW (file system). How can i get my windows 7 back
